# Change promise property to her value in Angular observable

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

I need to add values to the mapping of an array. That value comes from a promise and I can't add the value itself.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(data => this.getFiles(data.ref)),
    mergeMap((data, index) => {
      return data.map(item => Array(item, item.getDownloadURL(), item.getMetadata()))
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.listReferences = data;
    }
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the second mergeMap operator with map should work.

```
 .pipe(
   mergeMap(data => this.getFiles(data.ref)),
   map((data) => data.map(item => [item, item.getDownloadURL(), item.getMetadata()])
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
  this.route.params
.pipe(
  mergeMap(data => of(this.getFiles(data.ref))
    .pipe(
      map((item) => ({
        item,
        downloadUrl: item.getDownloadURL(),
        metaData: item.getMetadata()
      }))
    )
  ),
  toArray(),
)
.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.listReferences = data;
  }
);
```

Can you check this example. Is this similar your problem.
[Stackblitz exam](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-djd4cw)

Comment: does not work. where does the item come from? not making the map

Comment: @MiguelMüller sorry i fixed my error look my new answer

Comment: No... I had already tried that way. The map only runs once and not on each item.

Comment: is your getFiles function retuns an array? @MiguelMüller

Comment: can you check my stackblitz exam in answer? @MiguelMüller

Comment: Yes.. return a array of Reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the following solution

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(data => this.getFiles(data.ref)),
        map((data) => {
        const newArrayReferences = [];

        data.forEach(async (item, index) => {
            newArrayReferences.push({
            item,
            downloadUrl: await item.getDownloadURL().then((promisseReturn) => promisseReturn ),
            metaData: await item.getMetadata().then((promisseReturn) => promisseReturn )
            });
        });

        return newArrayReferences;
        }),
    )
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.listReferences = data;
        }
    );
}
```